# Turn off Vim spellcheck in custom region

Tags: vim, spelling

I have the following definitions in a .tex file preamble:

```
\newcommand{\beq}{\begin{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\eeq}{\end{eqnarray}}
```

If I then use `\beq` and `\eeq` to define an equation array region, spell checking is turned on in this region, where it would not be if I had used `\begin{eqnarray}` and `\end{eqnarray}`. I tried to turn off spell-checking in these custom regions using the method presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9520), i.e. copy the `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim` file to `~/.vim/syntax` and edit the file. I added a line like

```
syn region texZone start="\\beq" end="\\eeq\|%stopzone\>" contains=@NoSpell
```

to the file, but it didn't work. I am very unfamiliar with Vim syntax files, so I don't know how to debug this or take further steps. Any thoughts on how to turn off spell check just in my custom region would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

By placing that line by itself in `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` instead of adding it to a copy of `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim` in `~/.vim/syntax/tex.vim`, the spell checking behavior was disabled between `\beq` and `\eeq` tags as I wanted. Unfortunately, this line doesn't tell Vim it's a math region, so math syntax highlighting is different between these tags than it is between `\begin{eqnarray}` and `\end{eqnarray}` tags.